# How to push changes in bower dependencies?

Tags: git, github, polymer, bower

I have a demo webapp ( https://github.com/freedomotic/fd-polymer-webapp ) that relies on some Polymer elements that i published on customelements.io (some of them are listed here https://github.com/freedomotic ).

Since the demo webapp has these elements as bower dependencies I can't find a way to properly manage my workflow.
By now I modify these elements in my bower_components folder, then replace them in each distinct repository, push the changes and run bower update on the demo project to see if all runs smoothly. If yes, I push the demo project changes on the demo repository.

Is there a simplier way to handle this kind of workflow? Is it possible to link in some way those git repositories in my bower_components folder so that I can push changes directly from there?

Answer (score 0):

> By now I modify these elements in my bower_components folder

You probably shouldn't. If you think your fix is relevant to the community, find the source repository (which is not necessarily the repository that bower draws from) and open a pull request (which can be rejected by the authors)

If you want to modify it only for your purposes, try to override the functions or variables after including what ever library you need.

Also practical could be to just modify and pre-compile your dependencies into one file, which is less annoying to move around than a lot of bower_components

Comment: how would one "If you want to modify it only for your purposes, try to override the functions or variables after including what ever library you need."?

Comment: @Bren: For example if you were to import a class, you could assign what you need and then assign your own stuff next to it.

Do you have a concrete example?